# How to put navbar-brand to left and hamburger to right?

Tags: html, css

How can i put navbar-brand on the left and hamburger icon to the right? i tried floating in my css but it not working.. maybe because of the line that i marked on the code. In the photo is explained what i want to achieve. [Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOBQC.png)

```
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
    <div class="row mx-auto">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">
            <img src="Images/logo.png" width="65" height="50">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="home.html">Почетна<span
                        class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Информации</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Контакт</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Post your CSS also.

Comment: @justDan He's using bootstrap. There is no CSS

Comment: yes sorry i didn't say that im using boostrap 4

Comment: (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/hamburger-menu/) Look at this

Comment: You can also use the `float-left` and `float-right` classes provided by bootstrap

Comment: You can use flex-order to position them in the order you want regardless of the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this bootstrap 4 navbar snippet
https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/navbar-logo/
or use `float-left` and `float-right` bootstrap classes

Comment: thats working thanks, just one question how can i make in normal view on dekstop everything to be in center of the page?

Comment: If you want to make navbar items to be center then apply the following settings to **navbar-nav** class of ul and remove the **ml-auto** class from ul. `position: relative;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content-between`; Here's more [info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/).

```
<nav class="... d-flex justify-content-between">
    <!-- Your brand & content ||   [*****] link link link  -->
    <div class="...">
            <div class="brand-logo">...</div>
            <div class="hyperlinks">...</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Your menu -->
    <div class="menu">...</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to `.navbar`. no need to float them.